# How to use the function `Resolve` to verify this conclusion?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Let `A` be a non-zero square matrix of order n, $ A^{*}$ be the adjugate matrix of `A`, and $A^{T}$ be the transposition matrix of `A`. now we need to prove that when $ A^{*}=A^{T} $, $|A| \neq 0$ always holds.

```
adj[m_] := 
 Map[Reverse, Minors[Transpose[m], Length[m] - 1], {0, 1}]*
  Table[(-1)^(i + j), {i, Length[m]}, {j, Length[m]}]
Resolve[ForAll[{M ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals]}, 
  M\[Transpose] == adj[M], Det[M] != 0]]
```

The above code cannot verify this conclusion. What can I do to prove it?

Comment: Apart from the incorrectness of your Mathematica code you are confusing the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) and the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map).

Comment: @Natas Thank you for your guidance. If you can, please correct the grammatical errors in my question.

Comment: This is not about grammar, but about mathematical concepts. The adjugate of a matrix is related to its inverse and has nothing to do with the adjoint which is related to adjointness of linear maps. In general $\mathrm{adjugate}(M) \neq \mathrm{adjoint}(M) \equiv M^\mathrm{T}$.

Comment: In case you don't believe me `With[{m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]}, adj[m] == Transpose[m]]`. ;)